# How to select all parent checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm still very new to Javascript / Jquery and understand very little so far, but I need a function for my website. (Im sure its easy but yeah, so far i have not come to any result xD)

So my problem:

I have a form with list of checkboxes, all shown in an tree view.
I got the tree view from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_treeview.asp).

So my structure is exacly like on the w3schools.com page with the same css and javascript with the only difference that instead of normal text I have a form with checkboxes, here I have created an example:

```js
var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
  toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
    this.classList.toggle("caret-down");
  });
}
```

```css
/* Remove default bullets */
ul, #myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* Remove margins and padding from the parent ul */
#myUL {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Style the caret/arrow */
.caret {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none; /* Prevent text selection */
}

/* Create the caret/arrow with a unicode, and style it */
.caret::before {
  content: "\25B6";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

/* Rotate the caret/arrow icon when clicked on (using JavaScript) */
.caret-down::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

/* Hide the nested list */
.nested {
  display: none;
}

/* Show the nested list when the user clicks on the caret/arrow (with JavaScript) */
.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><span class="caret"></span><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Beverages
    <ul class="nested">
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Water</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Coffee</li>
      <li><span class="caret"></span><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Tea
        <ul class="nested">
          <li><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Black Tea</li>
          <li><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">White Tea</li>
          <li><span class="caret"></span><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Green Tea
            <ul class="nested">
              <li><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Sencha</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Gyokuro</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Matcha</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Pi Lo Chun</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What i want now is: For example, if you select "Matcha" from my example, I would like all parent checkboxes to be selected, ie "Green Tea", "Tea" and "Beverages".

But i dont know how to do that :(

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Can you please provide some code examples instead of links?

Comment: Plase post pieces of code of what you have tried.

Comment: This doesn't help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729193/how-to-get-all-parent-nodes-of-given-element-in-pure-javascript

Comment: As i said above, i dont understand much in javascritp :/ sorry

Comment: this is a duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892315/jquery-check-parent-checkboxes-in-nested-ul-li

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery Check parent checkboxes in nested ul li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892315/jquery-check-parent-checkboxes-in-nested-ul-li)

Comment: Yeah Rory provided me a solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can traverse the DOM to find the checkbox elements which are children of the parents of the checked box.

As you've tagged the question with jQuery, here's a solution using that framework:

```js
$('.caret').on('click', e => {
  let $target = $(e.target);
  $target.parent().children('.nested').toggleClass('active');
  $target.toggleClass('caret-down');
});

$(':checkbox').on('change', e => {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    $(e.target).parentsUntil('#myUL').children(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```css
ul,
#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#myUL {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.caret {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.caret::before {
  content: "\25B6";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.caret-down::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.nested {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><span class="caret"></span><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Beverages
    <ul class="nested">
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Water</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Coffee</li>
      <li>
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Tea
        <ul class="nested">
          <li><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Black Tea</li>
          <li><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">White Tea</li>
          <li>
            <span class="caret"></span>
            <input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Green Tea
            <ul class="nested">
              <li><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Sencha</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Gyokuro</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Matcha</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" value="xyz" name="xyz">Pi Lo Chun</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thats exacly what i wanted! Thank you very very mutch!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

here is a possible solution for your question.

1. Here added classnames to every possible level of lists, like level1, level2, level3 etc.
2. An event listener added for all the checkboxes *(inside the function i have write the conditions only for level4!)*
3. In the event listener function the code only checks for the event target state, so there is an important...

**TODO:** Implement the logic which checks, if any other element is selected in the same level!!

The function:

```
let checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

checks.forEach((box) => {
  box.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    var level = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.className;
    if (level == 'level4') {
      if (e.target.checked) {
        e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('input').checked = true;
        e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('input').checked = true;
        e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('input').checked = true;
      } else {
        e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('input').checked = false;
        e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('input').checked = false;
        e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('input').checked = false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

A [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dominagy/ehmf0a78/).

Anyway, this way it is pretty much "manual work" needed, my answers purpose is only to help to find a way of possible logic to achive your goal!

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) But Rorys solution is exacly what i wanted :D

Comment: Glad than :)
(And yeah, i didn't notice jQuery flag...)